# From Where news agency website manage their website?

Tags: web, server, backend, admin, web-frontend

Hello so i have a question.If a news agency web want's to post something to their web they need a admin dashboard for this,so my question is they have this admin dashboard as software or as another website hosted online.
I want to know this because i want to make a news website and i want to know is better doing this admin panel as software or as another hosted web.
Thanks everyone for answering!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a CMS. There are lots available.

Comment: You seem to think they need an admin dashboard. They do not. There are several mechanisms the editorial staff uses to preprint the actual paper, the workflow of that process is highly automated and includes feeding the website. Newswire service is also part of that workflow.